# Outlook VBA-- Some MailItem Properties return values, others do not

Tags: vba, outlook, mailitem

EDIT: New info: I just now realised that, while the return of Mailitem.Body is "", the actual value is "Application-defined or object-defined error" . I'm not entirely sure what that means, but I do know it shows up in multiple fields-- I included a screen shot below.

[image: errors]

I am having an issue where certain properties will return the correct value, and others will not. I have an example email, where I have an email with subject "Subject", the message is "Body", the sender email address is "email@address.com", and the date sent is 12 June 2013.

When I run the following code:

```
    Dim ComputerName As String
    Dim ErrorState As String
For Each MailItem In InboxItems
        ComputerName = MailItem.Subject
        'ErrorState = MailItem.Body
        ErrorState = MailBody(MailItem)
        strDate = GetDate(MailItem.SentOn)
        SenderEmail = MailItem.SenderEmailAddress
        If strDate = DateToday And SenderEmail = "email@address.com" Then
            Computers(a, 0) = ComputerName
            Computers(a, 1) = ErrorState
            a = a + 1
        End If
        Debug.Print MailItem.Subject
        Debug.Print MailItem.Body
    Next MailItem
```

What I get is ComputerName = "Subject", ErrorState = "", SenderEmail = "", and strDate = "2013/6/12" (which is the proper format in this case). Why would this return proper values for two of the Mailitem properties, but not for two of the others? This is a very strange problem, and I would appreciate any help you all might be able to give!

I will add more of the context for the code here:

```
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application", "localhost")
    Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = GetFolder("email@address.org/inbox")
    Set InboxItems = Inbox.Items
    InboxItems.SetColumns ("SentOn")
```

GetFolder is a function to get the mailbox by folder path. I have to do this because I am not using the default inbox in outlook.

I also tried using the MailBody Function proposed below, in case the body were in an HTML or RTF format. Unfortunately, it proved that the body was normal, and MailItem.Body should have retrieved it, and it still is not working. MailItem.Body returns "", even though I know that the email has a body. The body is just the number 1, and that is what I should be getting.

Also, I should note that the sender of the email is the same as the recipient; in other words, the email was sent from one email address to itself. I don't know if this could make a difference, but I figured that I would put it out there just in case.

Comment: How do you declare and assign `InboxItems`? Are you using `Option Explicit`?

Comment: @DougGlancy   I will edit in a larger portion of my code, give me a second

Comment: It seems to work for me, i.e., I get the Body and SenderEmail content. Good luck!

Comment: @DougGlancy Haha alright, at least I know the code does work. I'm just missing something... thanks for testing :)

Answer (score 7):

#### Multiple Item Types

First, there is no guarantee that all items in the `Inbox.Items` collection are of type `MailItem`. Inboxes also contain `AppointmentItem`, `MeetingItem`, and other `*Item` type objects. Not all of these item types have the same properties populated. To ensure you do not get a type mismatch error, declare your iterator variable as a generic `Object` and only assign it to a strongly-typed `MailItem` variable if it is of the correct type:

```
Dim oInbox    As Outlook.Folder
Dim oItem     As Object
Dim oMailItem As MailItem

Set oInbox = ActiveExplorer.Session.DefaultStore.GetRootFolder().Folders("Inbox")
For Each oItem In oInbox.Items
    If TypeOf oItem Is MailItem Then
        Set oMailItem = oItem
        ' Do stuff
    Else
        Debug.Print "Skipping " & TypeName(oItem)
    End If
Next
```

#### Optional properties

Second, there is no gaurantee that all properties of an object will be populated. If a mail item was never sent, it will have no sender address, and certainly it is possible to have an email with no body. A good way to get familiar with which properties are available and what they contain is to use the Locals window (View > Locals Window in the VBA IDE). Here's a screen shot of the above code paused in the loop, with some of the properties of the `oMailItem` object expanded:

[image: Locals Window in Outlook VBA IDE]

#### Body vs. HTMLBody

[`MailItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861332.aspx) objects have three body properties: [`Body`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304.aspx), [`HTMLBody`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941.aspx), and [`RTFBody`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867828.aspx). Usually only *one* of them is populated. Which one depends on the format of the email. You can check the [`BodyFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869979.aspx) property to find which one is applicable to the current item. Using that, here's a generalized way to get the raw body of a MailItem, no matter what the format:

```
Public Function MailBody(ByVal MailItem As MailItem) As String
    Select Case MailItem.BodyFormat
        Case OlBodyFormat.olFormatPlain, OlBodyFormat.olFormatUnspecified
            MailBody = MailItem.Body
        Case OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML
            MailBody = MailItem.HTMLBody
        Case OlBodyFormat.olFormatRichText
            MailBody = MailItem.RTFBody
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The problem is that, for the purposes of testing, there is only one email in the inbox, and it has a body and subject, and as it was received it does have a sender. Despite that, I am only getting two of the properties, the subject and date, whereas for body and sender email I am getting "". Thanks for your help so far though!

Comment: @Wolves I just updated my answer to include an additional point -- there are multiple `Body` properties you need to check. See my updated answer.

Comment: I will give that a try and get back to you. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Your function works fine; when I go though it step by step with F8, it goes into your function, and it just selects that first case, and sets MailBody to MailItem.Body, not HTML or RTF. This was a good idea, and something that I would not have thought of, but unfortunately it did not work; I still got as an output for the body, "". Thank you very much for giving this a go though!